# angular natives script solution not running in new xcode version

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-nativescript

I'm trying to run the existing angular native script solution in bellow environment. I'm getting the error while running it, please help me on resolving this issue.

- Mac Os: 13.3.1
- xCode: 14.3
- Node: 14.21.3
- Native Script: 6.1.0

**Solution Package.json file:**

[image: Image of package.json]

When i'm trying to run it's giving me the bellow error

ERROR:
**Building @nativescript/core for iOS requires NativeScript CLI with version at least 6.2.0. Please upgrade your NativeScript CLI version (npm i -g nativescript).**

this is the error i'm getting.

The same solution is worked with older Mac os and older xcode version. After updating to new OS and Xcode only not able to run the solution